# Swift Alamofire Error While Trying to Download File

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, info.plist

I want to download file from URL via Alamofire in Swift 4.
I'm new to swift and after hours trying to find out how to install the Alamofire library now I'm getting errors in the code.
Here is the code:

```
let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
        Alamofire.download(
            "http://handasaim.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/6-9.xls",
            method: .get,
//            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: nil,
            to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                //progress closure
            }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                //here you able to access the DefaultDownloadResponse
                //result closure
            })
```

The error I get:

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
2018-09-08 00:51:39.326074+0300 TrollingWithRoss[24805:2369287] Cannot start load of Task <CFB04BFF-0724-4AC2-84BA-74E56FFF821B>.<1> since it does not conform to ATS policy
2018-09-08 00:51:39.326266+0300 TrollingWithRoss[24805:2369283] Task <CFB04BFF-0724-4AC2-84BA-74E56FFF821B>.<1> finished with error - code: -1022
```

What changes I need to do to "info.plist" file?

the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>

</dict>
</plist>
```

If my code is bad please correct it, Im still a newbie.

Thank You,

Erel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your plist file and Problem solved :) "Swift 4"

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thank You!
Do you know how to use the file (where it downloaded?)

Comment: Now comes the hard part, parsing and displaying the data in the table. You can find relevant examples.

Comment: You should only allow insecure loads from the URLs you actually need, not all.